# Windows Batch file not changing directory Standard Error

Tags: python, windows, batch-file

I am trying to run a python file from a batch file.

It is working intermittently,
sometimes it is working, sometimes it is not.

Failed with below error:

```
Standard Error: System cannot find the path specified
```

Also the `cd` command is not changing directory when this error occurs. Sometimes it is working as expected.

*I feel there are two processes executing the batch file, one after the other, when this error is produced. When only a single process executes it bat, there are no issues.*

Here is my code:

```bash
REM SET PATH = "C:\Python3_9_2"
cd C:\Python3_9_2

C:\Python3_9_2\python.exe c:\Python3_9_2\test.py
```

**Update:**

I have `REM`arked the `SET` command line but `CD` is not changing to python directory. It is staying in `Windows/System32` only.

Comment: What are the permissions on the `C:\Python3_9_2` directory?  Are you running a command as some user that does not have permission to access that directory?

Comment: I suspect your issue arrises from this line: `SET PATH = "C:\Python3_9_2"`

First of all, why are you setting that variable if you never use it? Secondly, you're overriding the path environment variable, which can cause issues with running certain processes that rely on it. Also, your syntax is incorrect, it should be `SET "PATH=C:\Python3_9_2"`

Comment: If you want to add that folder to the PATH, then you should use the following command: `SET "PATH=%PATH%;C:\Python3_9_2"`

Comment: Then Why sometimes it is working as expected

Comment: That error is not a `cmd` error, so I suggest it's being generated by *python*. Try adding the line `echo %cd%&pause` after the `cd` line to verify whether the directory-change is effective. How did you determine that `t is staying in windows/syustem32 only` ?

Comment: Having read the comments and history : the line `SET PATH = "C:\Python3_9_2"` is **very** significant. First, this generates a variable named `PATH ` - with a trailing space. Second, `path` is a semicolon-separated list of directories that Windows searches for executables if an executable is not found in the current directory. To append `C:\Python3_9_2` to the list, use `set "path=C:\Python3_9_2;%path%"`. Note also that if there is no `setlocal` executed (normally at the start of the batch, after `@echo off`) then the directory will be accumulated into `path` each run in the session.

Comment: You don't say how you are running the batch file. It is important because you're now telling us that the Current Directory is `\Windows\System32` which implies you aren't running it in the usual manner.

Comment: A `cd` not changing the directory generally means you're trying to move to another drive and you need to use `cd /d` instead, but since Python is generating that error, I'd need to see your code to confirm.